# Number of all users registered on the system (not Active Directory)

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm trying to get a list of registered users on current system.

I tried gwmi win32_userprofile but confused on which line it is on.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get usernames with the Win32_UserProfile WMI class. You can get their LocalPath though:

```
$LocalPaths = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile | Select-Object -Property LocalPath
```

If you want all the User Account names, you'll have to user Win32_UserAccount. If you ARE hooked up to Active Directory and you just want the local accounts specific the machine, you can use this query:

```
$LocalAccount = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select Name, LocalAccount FROM WIN32_UserAccount WHERE LocalAccount=true"
```

If you want all accounts plus ones that have **potential** access, you can use this:

```
$PotentialAccess = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select Name FROM WIN32_UserAccount"
```

If you ARE on a domain, this one will take quite a while if it's an especially large domain as it retrieves every single user account that has access to the system.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get a list of local machine users:

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | select -expand name
```